# Seemingly error-free python codes experience unreasonably long running time

Tags: python, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
de=pd.read_csv('deal_level_data.csv')

import numpy as np

N = 24  
de.index = de.index * (N + 1)
de = de.reindex(np.arange(de.index.max() + N + 1)) 

def convert_int_with_NaNs(x):  
    try:  
        return x.astype('Int64') 
    except Exception:  
        return x 

de = de.apply(convert_int_with_NaNs)

for j in range(0, 14):  
    for i in range(0, len(de.index)):  
        if i % 25 == 0:  
            for a in range(1, 25):  
                de.iloc[i + a, j] = de.iloc[i, j]
```

It worked perfectly fine when I changed the '%' sign to something else (+, -, *, /). However, when % was used, the codes did not stop running even after a very long time. So, I would like to ask where the problem was, as the codes seemed to be logically correct. Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe you need `25 % i`?

Comment: the codes did not stop running usually because it enters an infinite loop, one direction is that you can check if the size of `de` keeps growing infinitely as `de.iloc[i + a, j] = de.iloc[i, j]`. Or give sample data of `de` so that other people can help